Modify Request In Spring Boot Before Controller With HandlerInterceptor
I found some resources about modifying request/request-body in spring boot before controller validation but HandlerInterceptor is not clear.
Link: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-change-request-body-before-controller
My code looks like:
@Slf4j
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class RequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object object) throws Exception {
        log.debug("1 - pre handle.");
        log.debug("METHOD type:" + request.getMethod());
        log.debug("Request URI: " + request.getRequestURI());
        log.debug("Servlet PATH: " + request.getServletPath());
        //check which controller method is requested
        if(object instanceof HandlerMethod){
            //can be added different logics
            Class<?> controllerClass = ((HandlerMethod) object).getBeanType();
            String methodName = ((HandlerMethod) object).getMethod().getName();
            log.info("Controller name: " + controllerClass.getName());
            log.info("Method name:" + methodName);
            return modifyRequest(request, response, (HandlerMethod) object);
        }
        return true;
    }

    private boolean modifyRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, HandlerMethod handlerMethod) throws Exception {
        ExtensionRequestWrapperHandler extensionRequestWrapperHandler = new ExtensionRequestWrapperHandler(request);
        return HandlerInterceptor.super.preHandle(extensionRequestWrapperHandler, response, handlerMethod);
    }
}

RequestWrapper:
public class ExtensionRequestWrapperHandler extends HttpServletRequestWrapper {
    private final HttpServletRequest originalRequest;
    private final String body;

    public ExtensionRequestWrapperHandler(HttpServletRequest request) throws IOException {
        super(request);
        this.originalRequest = request;
        this.body = this.inputStreamToString(callExtensionPreProcess());
    }

    @Override
    public ServletInputStream getInputStream() throws IOException {
        final byte[] myBytes = body.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return new ServletInputStream() {
            private int lastIndexRetrieved = -1;
            private ReadListener readListener = null;

            @Override
            public boolean isFinished() {
                return (lastIndexRetrieved == myBytes.length-1);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isReady() {
                // This implementation will never block
                // We also never need to call the readListener from this method, as this method will never return false
                return isFinished();
            }

            @Override
            public void setReadListener(ReadListener readListener) {
                this.readListener = readListener;
                if (!isFinished()) {
                    try {
                        readListener.onDataAvailable();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        readListener.onError(e);
                    }
                } else {
                    try {
                        readListener.onAllDataRead();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        readListener.onError(e);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int read() throws IOException {
                int i;
                if (!isFinished()) {
                    i = myBytes[lastIndexRetrieved+1];
                    lastIndexRetrieved++;
                    if (isFinished() && (readListener != null)) {
                        try {
                            readListener.onAllDataRead();
                        } catch (IOException ex) {
                            readListener.onError(ex);
                            throw ex;
                        }
                    }
                    return i;
                } else {
                    return -1;
                }
            }
        };
    }

    @Override
    public BufferedReader getReader() throws IOException {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.getInputStream()));
    }

    private InputStream callExtensionPreProcess() throws IOException {
        return ...getCustomInputStream();
    }

    private String inputStreamToString(InputStream inputStream) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        for (int length; (length = inputStream.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
            result.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        return result.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    }
}

And WebConfig:
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new RequestInterceptor());
    }
}

In this case, ExtensionRequestWrapperHandler getInputStream() doesn't trigger. Is there any suggestion?
